# How to get the values of a table generated in the jsp in the action in struts 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, struts, struts2-jquery

In my jsp I am selecting some values from one Table1 and adding it to another table Table2 by using the Add button. This is my jsp:

```
<%@page  contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" 
                                               pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s"uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#add').on("click", function(){
                $('#one tbody input:checked').parent().parent()
                                             .appendTo("#two tbody");
                return false;
            });

            $('#remove').on("click", function(){
                $('#two tbody input:checked').parent().parent()
                                             .appendTo("#one tbody");
                return false;
            });
        });


function GetCellValues() {
     var oTable = document.getElementById('two');
     var mycars = new Array();
     var mycars1 = new Array();
     var mycars2 = new Array();
        //gets table

        var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
        //gets rows of table

        for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
        //loops through rows

           var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
           //gets cells of current row
           var cellLength = oCells.length;
               for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
               //loops through each cell in current row
                  //get your cell info here
                  var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
                  alert(cellVal);
                  if(j==3){
                  mycars[i] = cellVal;
                  }
                  if(j==1){
                      mycars1[i] = cellVal;
                      }
                  if(j==2){
                      mycars2[i] = cellVal;
                      }
               }
        }
        window.location ="DynamicTable?mytable="+mycars;

 }
     </script>

</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="GetCellValues()">Submit</button>
    <table id="one" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <caption>Table 1</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th ></th>
    <th> Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>RollUp Type</th>
    <th>System</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="formList1">
            <tr>
            <td><s:checkbox theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    </td>
    <td><s:property value="id"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="named"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="status"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="type"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="rollup"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="unit"/></td>

            </tr>
            </s:iterator>
         </tbody>
    </table>

    <table id="two" style="border:1px solid green;">
        <caption>Table 2</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th ></th>
    <th> Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>RollUp Type</th>
    <th>System</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>

    </table>
    <br><hr><br>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <button id="remove">Remove</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here how do I retrieve the values that I added in Table 2 in my action when I click on Submit button in Struts2?

This is what I tried, I called the javascript GetCellValues() on click of Submit button, where I set each column in the array mycars,mycars1 and so on.

In my action class I have getters and setters for these arrays. But in my action I am not able to retrieve these values.

How to get the values of a table generated in the jsp in the action?

**UPDATE**:
I just corrected the line  `window.location ="DynamicTable?mytable="+mycars;` now i'm getting the values in the action as a String separated by commas. I would like to know if there is any other method than what I have used?

Comment: Use the standard method supported by your web server.

Comment: I used it but it does not worK

Comment: No, you didn't! If you did I'd see it.

Comment: +1 because I don't see any use of the jquery plugin, and it seems like you solved most of your own issue... couple things jsps generate html pages. Please say "How do I get the values of a table generated in the page to the action". We here (the struts2 community) understand struts2 tags but there is a much larger community that understand html and js/jQuery. Showing just the html would be best, when it comes to view issues concerning JS. To get the data back the the server is another issue, to do that look at the jquery ajax/getJSON methods. Also investigate the struts2-json-plugin.

Comment: I have never used struts2-json-plugin and have always struggled using even other struts2-ajax and struts2-jQuery plugins, it would be helpful if you can suggest me some example link to use these plugins

Comment: Just stick with the struts-json-plugin and the $.ajax and $.getJSON calls (I favour the later most often). After that it is just JS and jQuery. I hope you are using firebug! With firebug active put some console.log statements into your code to trace out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use hidden input fields for passing values to action class.
you can set those fields in java script which will be called onclick() of submit button.